# RubyMine - How to clone git hub project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, github, repository, clone, rubymine

I have a git repository and I want to clone it, but I have never done this using GitHub and RubyMine.

This is what I have till now:

1. SSH clone URL - from git hub
2. New SSH Key created for my PC and added in my Git Hub account
3. Ruby mine connection setting successful:

[image]

But when I copy the SSH clone URL in the environment I get the following error:

[image]

Can anyone assist me with the steps of cloning such repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Path to Git executable` is not your GitHub URL, you need to specify the path to the command line git client that will be used to perform commands:

`/usr/bin/git`

See also [this document](http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Using_Git_Locally).